# what is the strings-like lead in this trap song?

Tags: sound-design, synthesis, composition

For example Lil Boosie - Never Been a B*tch:

The chirpy top line melody in the first few bars. Does anyone recognize this sound? I have a nostalgic attachment to this era of trap music and I feel like that sort of lead (sounds almost like crickets) comes up in a lot of songs.

I've tried to recreate it in Ableton's wavetable starting with a trombone shape and a violin shape with different amounts of distortion and pitch bending but it's not coming out the way that sounds

Comment: Trap music/song ???

Comment: Yes, the one in the linked video?

Comment: It sounds like a really bad steel drum sample. (I gave it 15 seconds, that's all it's gonna get from me. That clap & "Yo, point at ma crotch, point at ma shoes" vocal style & I'm out;)